# Azure DevOps boards missing sprints/iterations

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

My Azure DevOps boards are not showing all sprints(iterations) in the Iteration selection for the filter. I am missing last month's sprint. I can find all work items through a query, and I have some items for sprints that do not show up. I made sure I am part of the team, ensured that the iteration belongs to the team iteration. See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that iterations show up only if they have items in *To Do* or *In Progress* status. If all items are *Done* iteration will not show up.